# Time Complexity for searching a record?

Tags: time-complexity

Suppose there are 100 000 riders in Delhi metro at a given time. The time we touch our smart card to exit from a station, it takes less than a sec time to retrieve our record and the machine displays our remaining balance. How could the machine search the unique card id in less than a sec,where as theoretically it should have taken (log n) time that would be 5 sec for 100 000 records?

Comment: You can't compare O() to real world without knowing exactly how fast a single operation is. e.g. if your DB is running on an original IBM PC, 8086-4.77mhz,  a single `n` will take a long time, v.s. running it on a modern multi-ghz cpu. they both essentially perform the same number of `n`, but the modern machine will do those `n` in MUCH less time.

Comment: Why would it take `log n` to search, presumably indexed, records? Any sensible hashtable implementation can search in `O(1)`, and as the card ids are under the metro's control there is no reason to assume that the hashing is imperfect. Even your laptop can lookup a value in a Java `HashMap` containing a few million entries in easily under a second...

Comment: you can use hash table so accessing cost is O(1)

Answer (score 0):

**Hash table- It would be O(1).** The unique IDs of the smart card will surely be stored in Hash table. If they store it in List, search operation should happen through a loop and take log n time, but Hash table will retrieve in just one call.